# How to add a special key to .Xmodmap?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xorg, hotkeys, xmodmap, awesome-wm

I have a SteelSeries 7g keyboard. You can see in the following picture that the "standard" windows key is replaced by the "Steelseries logo key".

I'm using Awesome Window Manager. I would like to `xmodmap` the steelseries key by the window key.

So I run the "showkey" application (also tried with "xev") but nothing happens when I press the Steelseries key.

Is there a solution to support this special key ? Maybe a driver ? Anybody has an idea?

[image]

Comment: You can't, this functions like `Fn` on a laptop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article [Mapping unsupported keys with xmodmap](http://dev-loki.blogspot.com/2006/04/mapping-unsupported-keys-with-xmodmap.html) explains how to use xev to detect unknown keycodes, and how to map them.

In addition, you might find useful the old [xkeycaps](http://www.jwz.org/xkeycaps/) program, which I believe is still part of most Linux releases.

If you find that the key does not generate any keycode or modifier, then you are out of luck.
In this case the BIOS handles this key, rather than Linux.

Comment: Looks like we're out of luck. Pressing the logo key under `xev` doesn't generate anything :-(